# Connection string to Oracle 11g from MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle11g, connection-string

I'm trying to connect to Oracle 11g from a clean install of MVC 3 (.NET) but I can't. I always get the same Exception: "ProviderIncompativeException".

I'm trying it from a clean installation of Visual Studio .NET, MVC3 and Oracle XE 11g.

My string connection is:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="OraAspNetConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost:1521/XE; User Id=PRUEBAS; Password=pruebas;"
    providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

The Oracle Database is running OK with this username and password and I'm pretty sure I'm installed all the Oracle drivers from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-101290.html

Anyone knows what could be happen?

Comment: Ok. It should work when using Visual Studio Ultimate and the "Model First".